# Ubuntu 18.04 login screen

Tags: boot

I have Citrix environment, I installed Ubuntu on a VM, after installation and updating with the updates, it is not booting anymore, even i tried fresh copy of it.
below is the screen after restart and it is like this no matter if I restart or shut it down.
any thoughts please?

/dev/xvda1:clean, 186531/65824 files, 2040532/2620928

it stays like this on black screen

Comment: The message you are seeing is a `fsck` report (file system check report) and usually is the result of an unclean shutdown the prior boot (or you've reached the counter [default is 30] boots and running it is a good idea).  Have you tried booting without 'quiet splash' to see if you get more messages, booting to runlevel 1?

Comment: sorry, i am totally new to Ubuntu, may i please request to tell me the procedure to do it..?

Comment: You didn't provide much detail (what Ubuntu 18.04 you installed, there are more alternatives  than I have fingers), but I'd hit <e> instead of enter (or waiting) at grub, removing the 'quiet splash' options as boot parameters (kernel line) where 'quiet' causes fewer[-to-none] messages to show, and 'splash' is a graphic that replaces the boot messages (in diagnostics these messages are useful even if end-users don't like them), and possibly adding a '1' to cause single-user or runlevel 1 to stop booting at (replacing your default runlevel/init level).

Comment: I have installed Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS in Citrix environment.

Comment: I don't know citrix, but I was thinking in terms of netboot, server, desktop, core, minimal, etc... all of which are Ubuntu 18.04 (plus some have  alternate installers) that have advantages/disadvantages let alone limits and different supported options etc.

Comment: I have installed it on Virtual machine using XenServer

Comment: The options I mentioned work on a virtual environment too; which is why I asked which Ubuntu 18.04 you installed as not all may provide grub which is what I'd change first; otherwise you'd I'd next boot a live (iso) & explore the logs that way (*again I'm thinking of vm but I have little experience on servers I don't have full control over*).